# can i stop peoples from pressing space to change to the next slide in powerpoint

Tags: animation, powerpoint

I am working on a PowerPoint game, and I need to stop people from skipping to the next slide by all means. I currently disabled the navigation bar and the clicking, but when I disable the navigation bar (look in the video), the animation for my spinning bar doesn't start automatically.

video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1RCVmOd54ZKgAE4xBrtCatrtunHhVBb/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Setup Slide Show in slide show panel.[image: ScreenShot]

then, use browse at kiosk.
The arrows should Disappear.
(I didn't use this, because it would prevent me from using other features of my game.)